# If you are a US Citizen, do you need a visa to travel to Ghana?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, ghana

I am traveling for one week to briefly work alongside a non-profit that is implementing a healthcare intervention in Ghana. I am a US citizen. Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**
 Yes

**Long Answer**:
You are required to have the following:

- Ghanaian visa application form
- Original, signed United States passport with at least 6 months of remaining validity
- Two passport-size photographs of applicant. Should be taken at least within the last three months
- Visa Fee -  money order, postal order, cashiers check or certified bank check
- Itinerary
- Evidence of financial support or letter of invitation from host in Ghana
- All persons entering Ghana are requested to have a valid certificate of immunization against yellow fever. Travelers may be required to present it at the port of entry in Ghana.
- Applications submitted by mail must be accompanied by prepaid self-addressed overnight, trackable envelope ( FEDEX) for return of passports. Only requests accompanied by certified prepaid return envelopes will be processed.

Source / Credit:
http://www.ghanaembassy.org/index.php?page=visas

Answer (score 1):

Yes you certainly have to get a visa for the purpose you want to travel for please see this links for more information [ghana visa processes](http://www.ghanaembassy.dk/content/visa-application)

To help you plan your trip you can also see these links as they come in handy

Also use the following travel blogs and websites to help you plan your travel to Ghana

[ghana travel blog for research](http://memorablevacationinghana.com/planning-your-trip-to-ghana/)